# Simple fetch with .@count predicate taking a long time (~30seconds)

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I have 2 entities, A and B that have a many to many relationship.

The A entity has about 10,000 objects in, and B has about 20 objects.

Basically, A objects can be related to one or more B objects, and the B objects keep track of which A objects they are connected to. This is done with the inverse relationship setting.

I simply wish to return every B object that is not related to an A object. The fetch I am using is this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetch setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
[fetch setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"B" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aObjects.@count == 0"]];
return [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];
```

However, it the fetch execution is taking a very long time, approx. 30 seconds. I don't understand this, because although there is a large number of A objects, this fetch has nothing to do with them, and just needs to check the 20 B objects.

If I comment out the predicate so the fetch returns all of the B objects, then the fetch is really quick, as you'd expect for just fetching 20 objects. So it would seem that that predicate is getting some A objects involved and is causing it to take a long time!

Can anyone shed any light on why this is taking so long?

**Edit:**

I've got SQL debug information and here's what's output:

```
CoreData: sql: SELECT t0.Z_ENT, t0.Z_PK FROM ZTABLEVIEWOBJECT t0 WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ZTABLEVIEWOBJECT t1 JOIN Z_10BOBJECTS t2 ON t1.Z_PK = t2.Z_10AOBJECTS3 JOIN ZTABLEVIEWOBJECT t3 ON t2.Z_12BOBJECTS = t3.Z_PK WHERE (t0.Z_PK = t2.Z_12BOBJECTS) ) = ? AND  t0.Z_ENT = ?) 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 49.4198s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 49.4240s for 0 rows.
```

I should add that both entity A and entity B inherit (have a parent) of a common TableViewObject entity, which holds common values between the two (such as table view section names and sort names etc). Hope this helps!

Comment: If you do the fetch request without the predicate and just have it return all of the B objects, how long does that take? If it's taking that long, it sounds like the A objects are somehow getting faulted in.

Comment: If I remove the predicate then the fetch is really quick! Sorry, should have mentioned that in the question! Yeah it's strange, I don't get why A objects are even looked at!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you have a many-to-many relationship between these objects and that may be causing your issue.  In a many-to-many there is a join table between B and A and that join table is probably getting hit hard.  I would be quite curious to see the SQL that is being generated with your fetch.

**UPDATE**

Try changing your predicate to be "aObjects == nil" and see what happens.  Because it is a many-to-many relationship that is the only other predicate that I can think of that *might* give you the results you are looking for.

Comment: I've just added the SQL output to the question, hope this helps diagnose it.

Comment: Ahh, I've just read up that it may be because of the inheritance (as they share a SQL table) causing all the rows to be processed. Would this make sense? Is the JOIN an additional problem or part of the same issue with the joint table? See: devforums.apple.com/message/153715#153715

Comment: Yeah the reason for this is the many-to-many relationship, and not the inheritance! I removed all the inheritance (took forever) only to find out it didn't make much of a difference! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for that update - interesting thought! I'll give it a try and get back to you!

Comment: It has been working for me under iOS 6. Do you have a test where it doesn't?

Answer (score 4):

you can replace

```
aObjects.@count == 0
```

with

```
ANY aObjects == nil
```

It's drastically reduce the time of my query (iPhone OS 3.0). It also works for `!= nil` (`@count != 0`).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using an SQLite store, you can turn on SQL debug logging. Core Data will log all the SQL commands it's making to the console.  I've found this very useful to discover something unexpected happening behind the scenes.  It will also print out timing information for each SQL command!

To do this, double-click the Executable in your project, go to the Arguments tab, and add an argument:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I believe the SQLDebug option isn't available on the iPhone.

Comment: Yes, it does work on the iPhone.  I did it yesterday.  If you Apple-R from Xcode, and run on the Device, stdout will go to XCode's console.

Comment: Ah great, it's working! Right, I'll see what SQL is being run.

Comment: Okay, I've added the output to the question, any idea?

Comment: Wow, 50 seconds!  It looks like Core Data is doing a JOIN, which means it has to check all the entries.  You might want to just add an optimization where a BObject sets an attribute hasAnAObject ;)

Comment: Ahh, I've just read up that it may be because of the inheritance (as they share a SQL table) causing all the rows to be processed. Would this make sense? Is the JOIN an additional problem or part of the same issue with the joint table? See: https://devforums.apple.com/message/153715#153715

Comment: It certainly looks like that's what happening. I think Marcus is better suited to know.  Dude wrote the book on it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a little bit late, but maybe this will help others that run into this problem.  The reverse relationship on `bObjects` is an attribute of `bObjects` and represented as an `NSSet` in `bObjects`. If either the `NSSet` is `nil` or the count of objects in the `NSSet` is zero, then there are no `aObjects` related to the particular `bObject`.

Testing for the `aObjects.@count` requires both tables representing the objects to be queried and is generating some really ugly SQL. What you are attempting here needs to look no further then the `bObject`.

Comment: testing for NSSet == nil doesn't work in iOS6 if there were previously objects there and now deleted. Testing for the count of objects ie NSSet.@count == 0 is slow - thats the whole point of this question.